# Can we tag a docker image remotely in nexus 3?

Tags: docker, nexus

Can we tag a docker image in nexus 3 docker hosted repo remotely using v2 api? I have enabled api when I created the hosted docker repo in nexus.

Comment: I don't believe so, but if Nexus fully supports the v2 api, a new `docker push` for an existing image with a new name should not upload the image layer blobs that already exist in the registry.

Comment: Nexus documentation says it supports v2 api